# Unhandled exception when call vc++ dll in vc++ code

Tags: visual-c++, dll, loadlibrary

I want to call my vc++ dll in my vc++ code.
but the error occur that **Unhandled exception at 0x00000000 in .exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.**

after last line.I have call vc++ dll by ordinal no.

In .h file

```
typedef int (*LPVAR)(char * ptr_f, char *CC);
```

In .cpp file

```
HINSTANCE hDLL;
hDLL = NULL;
LPVAR var;
hDLL = LoadLibrary("Prod.dll");


if( hDLL == NULL )
    AfxMessageBox("Could not load the DLL");

/*int ordinal = 2;
HMODULE  dll = LoadLibrary("Prod.dll");
FARPROC fn = GetProcAddress(dll, MAKEINTRESOURCE(ordinal));*/ //how to proceed after this.

else
{
    var = (LPVAR)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "Ver_C");
    char *ch,a;
    ch = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));

    a = 'z'; 
    int ans = var(ch,&a); //Unhandle exception after that.
}
```

Comment: what happens when you change var = (LPVAR)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "Ver_C");       to           var = new (LPVAR)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "Ver_C");

Comment: this error occur..."cannot convert from 'CProductionTestDlg::LPVAR *' to 'CProductionTestDlg::LPVAR'"

Comment: then put a * into that (LPVAR(probably here))

Comment: No this is not working:(

Comment: ok. forget all those. just change the declaration type to LPVAR*

Comment: This happens when you don't write any error checking code at all.  At least use assert().

Comment: @HansPassant,can you tell me how to impliment "assert" in this code or provide any link.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `var` function pointer is `NULL`. It means that `Ver_C` is not exported.

You can use `dumpbin.exe /exports Prod.dll` to check what functions are exported (and their names)

Comment: @vikky Can you print the value of `var` after calling `GetProcAddress`?

Comment: Value of var is 0x00000000. that means the function fails,what could be the reason for that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem were freelibrary after free it ans has currect value.

```
else
   {
    var =(LPVAR)GetProcAddress(hDLL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(2));
    char *ch,a;
    ch = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));

    a = 'z';
    int ans;
     ans = var(ch,&a);
     if ( hDLL != NULL )
             FreeLibrary( hDLL );
}
```